# Tag input field not working with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm trying to create a ruby on rails project, and as part of this project I'm using [this](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput) jQuery plugin to manage tags input. However the tag field works on first refresh but not after any page loads, I'm pretty sure this is a problem with turbolinks not running the js again.

So I installed [this](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem, and changed:

```
  $(function() {
    $("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

to:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[data-role=tagsinput], select[multiple][data-role=tagsinput]").tagsinput();
  });
})(window.jQuery);
```

in bootstrap-tagsinput.js.

However this is still giving me the same issues. Any help fixing this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try 'turoblinks:load'

instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

use:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load',function(){
```